# How to break UILabel's text on characters, not on words

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, line-breaks

I would like to achieve an effect that I would like to visually explain:

Let's say I have the word 'stackoverflow' that I would like to draw in a given UILabel in a constrained rectangle like so:

```
+---+ 
|sta|
|cko|
|ver|
|flo|
|w  |
+---+
```

So I would like to break strings or sentences based on their characters. Is that achievable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the line break mode: [NSLineBreakByCharWrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode) on the label if you're targeting iOS 6.0 and later, or [UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap) if targeting earlier iOS versions.

Comment: Oh, damn I tried that but my rect was too small. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Yeah, if your rect is smaller than the first char, nothing will appear :)